# Push notifications are not working in one ipod, rest of the devices iphone-4, iphone-3, ipod it's working fine

Tags: iphone, ios, urbanairship.com

I have implemented push notification using urban airship library, whenever I am sending push notification through urban airship portal, all the devices containing my app receiving the push notifications, except one ipod(iOS 4.2.1)device. so i debug through developer certificate it shown this below error

> Error: Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection
>   failure occurred: SSL problem (possibly a bad/expired/self-signed
>   certificate)" UserInfo=0x3a71f0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x3a5160 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -9807.)",
>   NSLocalizedDescription=A connection failure occurred: SSL problem
>   (possibly a bad/expired/self-signed certificate)}

and the devicetoken marked as inactive

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forget to check your device (select your iPod device) in your `MobileProvisioning Profile`.

Check mark your device and try with new `Profile` and let me know if you get errors.

Comment: I am using distribution certificate, so no need to add device for certificate right?

Comment: I am using distribution profile, so no need to add device UDID